# How to rotate around a corner when the distance is unknown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I feel like this is a solvable problem but I am just to stupid to solve it.

I want to able to move a player around a cube in third person in a 3D game. Before I worry about the corners where 3 edges of the cube meet I would first like to be able to move around two edges. If I use the LookAt method while jumping around a corner some problems occur with the vertical rotation of the player. So if he enters the trigger of the edge he turns around 180 degree somehow. That is why I am searching for a different solution.

[image: Green rectangle is the player. The dotted area is a trigger.]
(Green rectangle is the player. The dotted area is a trigger.)

So what I am given on the entry of the trigger is the edge position P2 and obviously the player position P3. The player should be able to stop the velocity while being mid air, so he could just fall down to the edge thanks to the gravity. That means that I can not just lerp it from the entry point to some exit point. The entry and exit points are dynamic.

What I already calculated is the distance from the player to the edge. Therefore I could tell if the player is closer to the right surface or the left surface judging by whether X or Y is higher.
But if the player enter on a higher position the numbers are also higher.

I am very confused about how to solve this. I need to lerp rotate the player around the corner P2 as long as he is within the two dotted lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something to get you started. This will rotate your player so that their down is pointing at the edge, and their forward vector tries to remain unchanged as much as possible. This will mean that moving in playerTransform.forward will move them where they are facing but will rotate them so that as they move around the edge, they will rotate around it.

```
transform playerTransform;

Vector3 edgeWorldDirection;
Vector3 edgeWorldPosition;

Vector3 playerWorldPosition;

// Determine up direction 
Vector3 player2Edge = edgeWorldPosition - playerWorldPosition;
Vector3 playerUpDirection =  (
        Vector3.Dot(player2Edge, edgeWorldDirection) * edgeWorldDirection  
        - player2Edge).normalized;

// rotate player to align local up with playerUpDirection and forward with 
// previous forward as much as possible.
Vector3 playerRightDirection = Vector3.Cross(playerUpDirection, playerTransform.forward);

// handle player looking "up"
if (playerRightDirection == Vector3.zero) playerRightDirection = player.Transform.right;

Vector3 playerForwardDirection = Vector3.Cross(playerRightDirection, playerUpDirection);

playerTransform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerForwardDirection, playerUpDirection);
```

For corners it's actually easier because your up is based on the location of the corner, you don't have to calculate the closest point on a line.

```
transform playerTransform;

Vector3 cornerWorldPosition;
Vector3 playerWorldPosition;

// Determine up direction 
Vector3 playerUpDirection = (playerWorldPosition - cornerWorldPosition).normalized; 

// rotate player to align local up with playerUpDirection and forward with 
// previous forward as much as possible. Same logic here as previously.
Vector3 playerRightDirection = Vector3.Cross(playerUpDirection, playerTransform.forward);

// handle player looking "up"
if (playerRightDirection == Vector3.zero) playerRightDirection = player.Transform.right; 

Vector3 playerForwardDirection = Vector3.Cross(playerRightDirection, playerUpDirection);

playerTransform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerForwardDirection, playerUpDirection);
```

Depending on how you're handling movement & player orientation, you may not actually want to rotate the player's transform, but with the results of `Quaternion.LookRotation(...)` you can multiply the local direction the player tries to go by that rotation to get the world direction that would correspond to.:

```
Vector3 localDesiredMove; 

Quaternion boxOrientationQuat = Quaternion.LookRotation(
        playerForwardDirection, 
        playerUpDirection);

Vector3 worldBoxOrientedMove = boxOrientationQuat * localDesiredMove;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It only works with one/four edges but I was able to edit it to work with all edges. Next up would be the corners, but that seems quite hard to do. Maybe I will just make the corners unwalkable...

Comment: For corners, it's actually easier. I added it to my answer. Just make sure you call the block of code that corresponds to if you're at a corner or at an edge.